# Caching lookup datatables in winforms application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, caching, dataset

I have a winforms application in VB that has a lot of lookup tables and a roster table(only updated once a week) where the data does not change often or ever.  I have a typed dataset in my application.  I want to be able to load the lookup tables once and use it anywhere in my application without having the fill it on every form.  One of the tables is an employee roster table (only updated once a week).  It has 10k+ rows.  What I am trying to do is load the roster table on application start, so it can be used during the application session.  Ive been searching for a way to do this.  I ran across caching, using the asp.net way, or the system.caching way, or creating a shared/static.  I cant figure out what is the best way to approach this or even where to begin.

I haven't really tried anything yet except searching for a solution.  I havent been able to find a complete solution as I do not understand most of it.

I know this isnt a perfectly formatted question, please forgive me.

Edit:  Per comments below, I tried this in application events:

```
Public rstrtbl As New TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable

Private Sub my_startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    Dim ta As New TaRRDataSetTableAdapters.TSTAFFRSTRTableAdapter
    rstrtbl = ta.GetData()
End Sub
```

Then in my form I sent the datasource of a control to my.application.rstrtbl.

Comment: Why not just put your data tables into global variables.  Load them at start up and they are accessible throughout the application.  Look at the Application Events

Comment: Pretty sure that's what a Module is for!

Comment: Typed `DataSets` contain types like any other. The fact that you are able to drag them onto a form in the designer doesn't mean that that is the only way they can be used. If you want an instance of your `DataSet` in code then create one in code. If you want to fill certain `DataTables` in that `DataSet` then do so. If you want to store that `DataSet` somewhere globally accessible then do so. The accessibility part is not related to the type so, if you could make a `String` or `Integer` globally accessible then you can do the same for a `DataSet`. If you can't, you can easily find out how.

Comment: Personally, if I need a global variable, I click the *View Application Events* button in the project properties and then declare a field or property there. That way, it is then accessible via `My.Application` in code, which seems logical. One advantage of that is that you can handle the `Startup` event in the same code file and initialise your global data, e.g. by querying a database, right there.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So if i look in application events, what do I do then?  do i do like dim rstrtbl as datatable then load that datatable.  then I can use that throughout the app?

Comment: That's kinda exactly what I said.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i editted my OP, did I do that right?  Also, can i do it in a background worker in that event as well?

Comment: Apart from the terrible names and the fact that a read-only property would be more appropriate than a field, there's no point creating a new `DataTable` first and then replacing it with another. If you don't want a new `DataTable`, don't create one. What you have will work but it could be better.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So do i just get rid of the new in Public rstrtbl As New TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable and add readonly after public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private _staffRosterTable As TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable

        Public ReadOnly Property StaffRosterTable As TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable
            Get
                Return _staffRosterTable
            End Get
        End Property

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            Using adapter As New TaRRDataSetTableAdapters.TSTAFFRSTRTableAdapter
                _staffRosterTable = adapter.GetData()
            End Using
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Appropriate place, sensible name and a read-only property. You can then access that table using `My.Application.StaffRosterTable` anywhere in your project. As I said, it's not necessary to do that but it is logical.

Note that I also used the navigation bar at the top of the code window to generate the event handler, so it also uses a sensible, standard name.

EDIT:

If you want to use lazy-loading, which was not part of the original question, then you can do something like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
    ' The following events are available for MyApplication:
    ' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
    ' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
    ' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
    ' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
    ' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.

    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        Private _staffRosterTable As TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable

        Public ReadOnly Property StaffRosterTable As TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFRSTRDataTable
            Get
                If _staffRosterTable Is Nothing
                    Using adapter As New TaRRDataSetTableAdapters.TSTAFFRSTRTableAdapter
                        _staffRosterTable = adapter.GetData()
                    End Using
                End If

                Return _staffRosterTable
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: What if I want to only load the table when it is first called, then any other calls, checks to see if it is filled, if it is, then it uses it otherwise it loads it.  Does that make sense

Comment: Thank you my friend.  Is this way better than using system.runtime.caching?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a module in VB.  Add a module to your project like this:

```
Module Globals

  Public employeeRosterTable As employeeRosterTableType

End Module
```

then somewhere in your start up code (for example the Load event of your Start-up Form, or after login or wherever suits), you can create & populate it.

As it's in a module, it's accessible throughout your project.